# Interactive rebase keeps adding steps after trying to squash a commit

Tags: git

When rebasing my branch on itself in order to clean up commits through squashing them together my rebase gets stuck in a loop, not sure how to break this. This is for every branch that I am working on, not just one specifically.

For example say I have a branch **my-branch** with three commits

```
commit 1
commit 2
commit 3
```

In my terminal, I write `git rebase -i origin my-branch`

Which brings me to the interactive git (in my case on Sublime text)

Here I see all my commits and change the last one to squash so that I only have commit 1 and 2:

```
p commit 1
p commit 2
s commit 3
```

From here, I see another interactive window, in which I remove the commit message for commit 3, leaving only the commit 2.

This all seems to be working however now am caught in a loop.

For example on my terminal it is on the rebase STEP 3/3 then I do `rebase --continue` it continues to STEP 4/4 (with no changes) `rebase --continue` again STEP 5/5 and so on without actually leaving the rebase.

I am forced to use `rebase --abort` and my commits are not squash.

Comment: Following the general procedure you've outlined, I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe. Specifically, after I save-and-quit the second editor (the commit message), the rebase completes as it should.  It might help if you can post an exact transcript of a rebase session behaving in this way

Comment: What version of Git are you using? I have a very vague recollection of a bug like this in some ancient Git, such as 2.3 or something.

Comment: I think this is it, actually was using git version 2.27

Answer (score 1):

If you want to squash to in the end rebase, you could skip using rebase -i altogether with this trick:

```
git checkout my-feature
git merge master # merge with the branch you want to rebase onto
# don't worry, that will go away with the following steps
git reset --soft master # move branch pointer to master, all changes between your branch and master (theoretically speaking, all changes related to your feature _only_ will be in index
git commit -m "My feature"
```

That's it.